How to mock Dependency class in Fast API
I have a simple Authorizer class
class ScopeAuthorizer

    def __init__(self, scope: str):
        self.scope = scope
    def __call__(self, request: Request):
        # validate request based on required scopes for request


define a route
@router.post("/my_route", status_code=200)
async def my_route(
    scope_authorized=Depends(ScopeAuthorizer(["user:write"])
):

Now I want test out the route and mock ScopeAuthorizer all together
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
# import app
class MockPermissionScopeChecker:
    def __init__(self, scopes):
        self.scopes = scopes
    def __call__(self, request: Request):
        return False
class TestRoute(unittest.TestCase):
   def test():
      app.dependency_overrides[ScopeAuthorizer] = MockPermissionScopeChecker # did not work
      app.dependency_overrides[ScopeAuthorizer('foo')] = MockPermissionScopeChecker # did not

I want to test out the behavior of the app when authorization fails or succeeds but somehow not able to mock the entire class.
This is relevant post I found https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi/issues/2795 but I cannot have a frozen dataclass as scope will change for reach request

The issue stems from your dependency being a difference reference each time you instance it - calling ScopeAuthorizer('foo') twice will give you two different objects. That means that dependency_overrides has no way to know that those two objects are the same logically - since they're not the same object.
You can work around that by making sure that you only have one instance being returned for each different key you give your authorizer, since that means that the reference in dependency_overrides will be the same as the reference given to Depends:
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def get_authorizer(scope: str) -> ScopeAuthorizer:
    return ScopeAuthorizer(str)


def foo(scope_authorized=Depends(get_authorizer("user:write")):
    ...


# this will now refer to the same object as `Depends` above:
app.dependency_overrides[get_authorizer("user:write")] = my_custom_authorizer


Will it work for the multiple scopes, though? Sounds like the only way would be to create multiple app.dependency_overrides for an each scope.

Yes, you have to add an override for each scope (as you're effectively overriding the returned object from the function, not the function itself). And using a mutable data structure such as a list as an argument will not work, as it'll be a different list every time it appears in a different location.

Yeah, so in the end might be better to stick with mocker.patch if you have multiple scopes. It might violable solution if there are a few of parameters, though.

There is not way to override dependencies that use parameters. Because it will have a different key value in a dictionary after you override it.
If you didn't have parameters you could like this:
class ScopeAuthorizer
    def __call__(self, request: Request):
        # validate request based on required scopes for request

scope_authorizer = ScopeAuthorizer()

And then in tests overwrite it like this:
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import app

class MockPermissionScopeChecker:
    def __call__(self, request: Request):
        return False

class TestRoute(unittest.TestCase):
   def test():
      app.dependency_overrides[ScopeAuthorizer] = MockPermissionScopeChecker()

Better to use mocker.patch in this kind of situations

An alternative is to wrap it in a function that has a cache decorator - that way the same object or wrapped function will be returned for the same parameter each time, Since the same instance gets returned, dependency_overrides will work as expected. functools.lru_cache works fine to create such as cached function.
